# Collection View layout bug when selectItem (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionview, swift5

After selecting cell from viewDidLoad Layout is change

**Before select cell**

[image: Before select cell]

**After select cell**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: SelectedFolderIndex, section: 0)       
collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .centeredVertically)
```

[image: After select cell]

**Layout**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/2.2, height: 55)
}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 7, left: 12, bottom: 12, right: 12)
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 11
collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Comment: implement minimum spacing method

Comment: @SPatel He is already added layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5; layout.minimumLineSpacing = 11

Comment: just try with


`layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero`
`layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0`

Comment: @SPatel It works, but how to add padding for cells now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cut insets and spacing from cell width:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (collectionView.frame.width/2.2) - 2*12 - 11
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 55)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `scrollPosition: .centeredVertically` you are setting that after the scroll al the items will be positioned in the center and aligned vertically, like you can see in your case. Try look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618057-selectitem for change the behavior you want