# UICollectionViewFlowLayout issues

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Apologies in advance but I've been going around in circles on this for days...

I have a `UIViewController` that is presented from another VC (in my case, a button is tapped).  The new VC (code below) is made up of:

1. a `UITextView` which dynamically increases in height based on content the user types in
2. a `UIView` which has a fixed height

and then below that, to the bottom of the ViewController view, is a UICollectionView.  This has 5 sections in it that horizontally scroll.  I will be inserting different content into each of those 5 cells but am just having issues at the moment when the UICollectionView resizes.  I've been able to get most of them cleared except for one.

This error can be reproduced whenever the `UITextView` increases in size to between 3-6 lines long, and again at 13 lines...  This happens in the simulator using e.g. an iPhone 8 plus but on an iPhone 11 Pro Max, it only happens around 19 lines of text in the `UITextView`.

I am using TinyContraints here but I've tested using traditional programmatic constraints and had the same issue.

```
//
//  NewItemVC.swift
//

import TinyConstraints
import UIKit

class NewItemVC: UIViewController {

    let titleField = UITextView()
    let bannerContainer = UIView(frame: .zero)
    var flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    lazy var horizontalCV = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)

    let genericCellID = "genericCellID"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .orange

        setupHeaderArea()
        setupBannerArea()
        setupHorizontalCollectionView()
    }



    func setupHeaderArea(){

        titleField.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        titleField.textContainerInset.top = 55
        titleField.textContainerInset.bottom = 20
        titleField.textContainerInset.left = 15
        titleField.textContainerInset.right = 15
        titleField.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

        // add to main view & position
        view.addSubview(titleField)
        titleField.topToSuperview()
        titleField.leftToSuperview()
        titleField.rightToSuperview()

        titleField.isScrollEnabled = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateTextFieldHeight), name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

        // add a header label
        let headerLabel = UILabel()
        headerLabel.textColor = .systemBlue
        headerLabel.text = "NEW ITEM"
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)

        view.addSubview(headerLabel)
        headerLabel.topToSuperview(offset: 35)
        headerLabel.leftToSuperview(offset: 20)
        headerLabel.height(13)

        // add card handle
        let handle = UIView()
        handle.backgroundColor = .black
        handle.alpha = 0.2
        handle.width(45)
        handle.height(5)
        handle.layer.cornerRadius = 5/2

        view.addSubview(handle)
        handle.topToSuperview(offset: 10)
        handle.centerXToSuperview()

    }



    func setupBannerArea(){

        // position container
        view.addSubview(bannerContainer)
        bannerContainer.topToBottom(of: titleField)
        bannerContainer.edgesToSuperview(excluding: [.top, .bottom])
        bannerContainer.height(62)
        bannerContainer.backgroundColor = .cyan

    }



    func setupHorizontalCollectionView() {

        horizontalCV = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        horizontalCV.dataSource = self
        horizontalCV.delegate = self

        horizontalCV.backgroundColor = .yellow
        horizontalCV.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        horizontalCV.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        view.addSubview(horizontalCV)
        horizontalCV.topToBottom(of: bannerContainer)
        horizontalCV.edgesToSuperview(excluding: .top)

        horizontalCV.isPagingEnabled = true
        horizontalCV.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

        horizontalCV.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: genericCellID)

    }



    @objc func updateTextFieldHeight() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.horizontalCV.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }


}


// MARK:- Delegates - UITextViewDelegate

extension NewItemVC: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let size = CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .infinity)
        let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)

        textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in

            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
            }
        }
    }

}



// MARK:- UICollectionView Data Source

extension NewItemVC: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: genericCellID, for: indexPath)
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = .orange
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }
        return cell
    }

}



// MARK:- Delegates - UICollectionView Flow Layout

extension NewItemVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let requiredHeight = self.view.frame.height - (titleField.frame.height + bannerContainer.frame.height)
        let requiredWidth = view.frame.width

        return CGSize(width: requiredWidth, height: requiredHeight)
    }

}
```

From what I've been able to tell, there's some issue randomly where the collectionView frame and the contentSize are out by 24 points but I can't work out why/where etc...

The error is as follows:

```
2020-02-06 20:39:18.425280+1100 Scrolling[67237:8005204] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-06 20:39:18.425378+1100 Scrolling[67237:8005204] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2020-02-06 20:39:18.425672+1100 Scrolling[67237:8005204] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fcf56d4a120>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fcf5785d000; frame = (0 208.667; 414 487.333); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000ce8a50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000213a00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {2070, 511}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fcf56d4a120>; dataSource: <Scrolling.NewItemVC: 0x7fcf56d20110>>.
2020-02-06 20:39:18.425760+1100 Scrolling[67237:8005204] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59942752/6630644

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that and maybe I'm not understanding the problem but I'm already setting the insets to 0 in setupHorizontalCollectionView()

Comment: `let requiredHeight = collectionView.frame.height - (titleField.frame.height + bannerContainer.frame.height)`
        `let requiredWidth = collectionView.frame.width`

Comment: where is constraints for collectionview?

Comment: Constraints for the collectionView are under the method setupHorizontalCollectionView.  The top constraint is set to the bottom of the bannerContainer as well as the remaining sides to the superview.

Comment: @SPatel - regarding your other comment where you suggest a different calculation for the `requiredHeight` value.  If I do this, then the collectionView cell renders incorrectly and I have a big gap above the cell and below the cell.  But I think that's because it's then taking away the height of the `titleField.frame` and the `bannerContainer.frame`.  So if I remove those from the equation and just use the `collectionView.frame`, it seems to work.  Just testing further now.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what is the issue that you're having? I am not sure I understood what your problem is exactly.